# Update QThread from GUI Widgets

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I've seen this question asked in reverse a bunch of times - how to update the GUI from a subclassed QThread - but I actually want to do it in reverse. I have an application which displays the feed from a camera continuously and indefinitely, and the camera runs in a separate thread. I have the camera feed displayed in the GUI using signals from the QThread. The camera controls are in the main GUI window, and I want to be able to send those updates to an already-running camera thread. What would be the best way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default [`QThread::run()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#run) implementation which runs an event loop, then you can create a slot on the class and invoke it as a [QueuedConnection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) (which should occur automatically).

Otherwise, you'll need to use standard thread synchronisation primitives, such as [`QMutex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmutex.html) to safely access the same data from both threads.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too knowledgeable in this stuff, but when you said default run() implementation...I've written my own run() method for my subclassed QThread, so does what you said there still apply?

Comment: If you've written your own run method, then you can't use the Qt slots system unless you call [QThread::exec()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qthread.html#exec) which is what run calls by default.